# Recursive list-iterations in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am attempting to update my Result variable with in the case that some element in a list passes the `aboveThreshold` filter. (The element needs to be above 40)

This will be performed on the given condition for the whole list, or so I want it to, but with the following code it seems I only allow for a single iteration.

```
test([],X,Result).

test([H | T],X,Result) :-
    aboveThreshold(H),
    Result is X + 1000,
    test(T,Result,Result) ;
    test(T,X,Result).
```

I base my conclusion on the following Prolog console print:

```
test([71,41,41,40],0,R).
R = 1000.
```

Comment: What is `calcPayment`?  What is it used twice, with a `;` between?  Why does the case case have 2 variables that are only used once?  Did you even test the base case?

Comment: Old name, forgot to change it here. The base case is just making sure my predicate succeeds as intended.

Comment: Don't use `Result` in `Result is X + 1000`, use another variable name like `Y`. Then on the line right after it call `Y` instead, ie `test(T,Y,Result)`. Also your base case should be `test([],Result,Result)`. But i don't understand your example: shouldn't R be equal to 0 since none of the elements of the list are above the threshold 100?

Comment: The meaning of `test([], X, Result).` is unclear, and would give you singleton warnings. What does `X` represent in the `test` predicate? `test([], X, Result).` should yield the result you want if the input list is empty. What result do you expect for an empty list? Or should it fail? If fail, then it's the wrong base case, and maybe your base case should have a one-element list. As @Fatalize points out, your example is confusing since it seems to contradict your description. So your description needs to be clarified, or you example fixed.

Comment: as Fatalize & lurker points out, the example of aboveThreshold logic is indeed contradictory to my example. This is due to some refactoring I had done yet not updated within my StackOverflow post. I expected it to pass 71, 41 & 41. But thanks to you both I have corrected the issue and addressed the base case which produces the correct result. My post has been edited and clarified for the potential benefit of others :)